# Exercise 33 Chapter 6 Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space, Frank Jones.

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that $\overline M$ is the σ-algebra generated by the collection of sets which either belong to $M$ or are subsets of μ-null sets.

Where $X$,$M$,$μ$ is a given measure space and $\overline M$ = $ \{A\cup N |A\in M,N\subset F$ for $F\in M$ and $ μ(F)=0\} $; $X$,$\overline M$,$\overline μ$ is called the completion of $X$,$M$,$μ$.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: As an aside, one usually talks about a completion rather than the completion. The above is the smallest completion, but in general there may be many completions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\emptyset=\emptyset \cup \emptyset$ so it belongs to $\overline{M}$

Let $B=A \cup N$ such that $N \subset F$ for some $F \in M$ with $\mu(F)=0$

Then $B^c=(A\cup F)^c \cup F\setminus (A \cup N)$ thus it belong to $M$

If $B_n=A_n \cap N_n$ disjoint sets and $F_n \in M$ such that $N_n \subseteq F_n, \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ with $\mu(F_n)=0$ , then $\bigcup_nB_n=(\bigcup_nA_n) \cup (\bigcup_nN_n)$

where $\bigcup_nA_n \in M$ and $\mu(\bigcup_nN_n) \leq \sum_n\mu(F_n)=0$